# Artificial Limb Transplant ( Prothesis) in Rig-Veda?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, identification-request

In medicine, a  [**Prosthesis**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthesis) , is an artificial device that replaces a missing body part lost through trauma, disease, or congenital conditions.
prosthetics is simply replacement of missing limbs.

My question is - In which verse of Rig-Veda there is mentioning  of prosthetics?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RV 1.112, 116, 117, 118 mention of Vispala which is either a woman or a mare. She lost a limb in a war or Khela (battle or competition) and *Ashvins* replaced the lost one with a metal leg

[image]

**1.112 (10)**

> yābhirviśpalāṃ dhanasāmatharvyaṃ sahasramīḷha ājāvajinvatam | 
>   yābhirvaśamaśvyaṃ preṇimāvataṃ tābhir... ||
>
> Those with which you revived Viśpalā, to pursue the way, to gain the
>   stakes in the contest with a thousand battle-prizes with which you
>   helped Vaśa Aśvya and Preṇi [?]‌—with those forms of help come here, o
>   Aśvins.

**1.116 (15)**

> caritraṃ hi verivāchedi parṇamājā khelasya paritakmyāyām |  sadyo
>   jaṅghāmāyasīṃ viśpalāyai dhane hite sartavepratyadhattam ||
>
> Because her foot was cut away like the wing of a bird, in the contest
>   of Khela, at the decisive turn, right away you inserted a metal shank
>   for Viśpalā to run, when the stake had been set.

**1.117 (11)**

> sūnormānenāśvinā ghṛṇānā vājaṃ viprāya bhuraṇā radantā |  aghastye
>   brahmaṇā vāvṛdhānā saṃ viśpalāṃ nāsatyāriṇītam ||
>
> Being sung by Sūnor Māna [=Agastya], o energetic Aśvins, digging out
>   victory’s prize for the inspired poet, and growing strong alongside
>   Agastya through his poetic formulation, you draw Viśpalā back
>   together, Nāsatyas.

**1.118 (8)**

> yuvaṃ dhenuṃ śayave nādhitāyāpinvatamaśvinā pūrvyāya |  amuñcataṃ
>   vartikāmaṃhaso niḥ prati jaṅghāṃ viśpalāyā adhattam ||
>
> You swelled the cow (with milk) for Śayu of long ago, who needed help,
>   o Aśvins.You released the quail-hen from tight straits, and you
>   inserted a shank for Viśpalā.

Comment: Nice find. Can you update the answer with original verses? Also is there any other place in Rig-Veda other than mandala one this is mentioned.? Here is the link.- http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01118.htm

Comment: @shanu Good to see your interst in Rig Veda:)

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda thanks :) during my PhD, these were my side studies :)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I added the original texts also